# How to execute a yes on the Powershell terminal?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I use Powershell ISE to do a script. I want to execute a .bat with this script :

```
path\i_all.bat
```

This .bat asks me if I want to continue by entering yes or no but from the terminal I can't do it.

```
Do you want to continue (yes/no) ?
```

I want to enter yes in my program. Is it possible to do this in Powershell ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't do it?' Are you unable to write? Does the bat give an error? are you sure the right inputs are 'yes' / 'no' and not 'y' / 'n' ?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `path\i_all.bat` from your PowerShell Script, send the 'yes' string through a pipe, the batch script i_all.bat will take the pipe output as its stdin :

```
Write-output "yes"|path\i_all.bat
```